# Google Spanner: How to list databases?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-spanner

Using C#, I am trying to list the available databases on a Google Spanner Instance.  There seems little to no decent documentation that actually explains how to use the `Google.Spanner` Nuget libs.

From what I can tell there are a few libraries to use.  The first is the main **SpannerClient** which gives you a client to execute sql queries on a given database.  I have this working fine.  However in order to present the list of available databases to my users, I'd like to get the list of available databases.  I have found the package `Google.Cloud.Spanner.Admin.Instance.V1`; but almost no docs to explain how to use.  So I've been coding in the dark, so far I've written the following test code:

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(_apiKey);
var client = new InstanceAdminClientBuilder();
client.Credential = credentials;

var clientInst = client.Build();
ListInstancesRequest listInstanceRequest = new ListInstancesRequest();
listInstanceRequest.Parent = _projectId;
var res = clientInst.ListInstances(listInstanceRequest);
```

I get an:

> "InvalidArgument - Invalid ListInstances request."

Which suggests I've not done it right but I can't find any decent docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listing *instances* isn't the same as listing *databases*. If you want to list databases, you should use the `Google.Cloud.Spanner.Admin.Database.V1` package, with `DatabaseAdminClient`.

Next, the `Parent` property in any list operation should be the full resource name, e.g. `projects/my_project_id` rather than just the project ID. Normally the best way of approaching this is to use the generated [resource name types](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/resource-names).

So for example:

```cs
var client = DatabaseAdminClient.Create();
var instanceName = new InstanceName(projectId, instanceId);
var databases = client.ListDatabases(instanceName);
foreach (var database in databases)
{
    Console.WriteLine(database.Name);
}
```

If you want to list the instances for the project, you'd use:

```cs
var client = InstanceAdminClient.Create();
var projectName = new ProjectName(projectId);
var instances = client.ListInstances(projectName);
foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance.Name);
}
```

Comment: I am now having a similar issue with creating the Spanner Client connection.  It works with default credentials but doesn't seem to allow me to provide custom credentials? Happy to raise a new question if preferred?

Comment: @Spanners: A new question would be better, so that we know *exactly* what type you're interested in. If you're using the ADO.NET provider, that doesn't use this pattern - and currently there's no *simple* way of providing a custom credential. I'll raise an issue to address the simplicity, but it's still feasible - I'll answer the new question.